How does the Raspberry Pi 5 compare to the Raspberry Pi 4?
I’m particularly interested in understanding the following aspects:

Performance improvements in terms of CPU, GPU, and RAM
Compatibility with existing HATs and peripherals
Differences in power consumption
Enhanced I/O options and connectivity

For those who have worked with both models, is the newer version worth it?

Have you tried Googling it yourself? This doesnt sound like asking for a  recommendation
